# To put objects with same value in parameter to an array

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I am trying to put objects with same value in parameter to an array.  For example,

```
 Student a = new Student("Abigail", 1, 5);
        Student b = new Student("Benny", 1, 6);
        Student c = new Student("Charles", 1, 10);
        Student d = new Student("Denise", 2, 12);
        Student e = new Student("Eleanor", 2, 9);
        Student f = new Student("Fred", 2, 5);
```

For this code, 1 means bus route one, and 2 means bus route 2.  I want the people with the same route to be in an array using a method, instead of manually plugging the objects inside array.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you know exactly how many routes and students you have?

Comment: There are only two routes and all the students are mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a `Multimap` or a `Map<Integer, List<Student>>`:

```
private final Map<Integer, List<Student>> buses = new HashMap<>();

public void addStudent(Student s) {
    buses.computeIfAbsent(s.getRoute(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s);
}
```

This of course assumes `Student#getRoute` returns that number you provided to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BusRoute {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student("Abigail", 1, 5);
        Student b = new Student("Benny", 1, 6);
        Student c = new Student("Charles", 1, 10);
        Student d = new Student("Denise", 2, 12);
        Student e = new Student("Eleanor", 2, 9);
        Student f = new Student("Fred", 2, 5);

        Student[] students = Student.getBusroute(2, a, b, c, d, e, f);
        System.out.print(students);
    }

    static public class Student {
        String name;
        int busRoute;
        int age;
        Student(String name, int busRoute, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.busRoute = busRoute;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getBusRoute() {
            return busRoute;
        }

        static public Student[] getBusroute(int busRoute, Student ...students) {
            return (Student[])Arrays.stream(students).filter(student -> student.getBusRoute() == busRoute).toArray();
        }
    }
}
```